# How can I improve performance of Lucene Highlighter operations?

Tags: performance, lucene, lucene.net, lucene-highlighter

I have prototyped a search/browse application in C# using Lucene.Net. The source data is a single modest 5MB XML file (containing about 900 "documents") that I index using Lucene. My searches are working fine and are plenty fast. For this application, browsing and viewing each "hit" document is important, so the user can select a hit and see a complete view of that document (which usually fits inside half the screen), and I need the matching search terms highlighted in that view. I am using WPF and an MVVM approach. The document view is currently implemented with about a dozen ContentControls of which six are for displaying searchable fields that use a highlightConverter.

The performance was quite poor, so I added stopwatch timing to isolate the problem. The HighlightSearchTerms method in my model seems to be the culprit (about 100-600 ms to execute). If I short-circuit this method to just return the input text, the performance is fine.

Here is the method:

```
_analyzer is a StandardAnalyzer(_luceneVersion)
_parser is a QueryParser(_luceneVersion, “content”, _analyzer)
_formatter is a SimpleHTMLFormatter(“|~S~|”, “|~E~|”);

private string HighlightSearchTerms(string text, string queryString)
{
    var query = new BooleanQuery();
    query.Add(_parser.Parse(queryString), Occur.SHOULD);
    var fragmentScorer = new QueryScorer(query);
    var highlighter = new Highlighter(_formatter, fragmentScorer);
    highlighter.TextFragmenter = new NullFragmenter();
    var tokenStream = _analyzer.TokenStream(null, new StringReader(text));
    string highlightedText = highlighter.GetBestFragment(tokenStream, text);
    return highlightedText == null ? text : highlightedText;
}
```

A few years back I read the "Lucene In Action" book and have again thumbed through relevant portions to see if I could get any ideas. I've also searched the net a good bit. So, here are a couple of questions or areas of possible exploration.

1. Can I omit scoring somehow? I don't need to show context of matching
   search terms, so I don't need to break up the hit document into
   fragments and get a "score" for the various fragments. I want the
   list of hits shown by title and then when the user selects one hit, 
   the whole hit document is displayed with highlighting. I see how to 
   use NullFragmenter and GetBestFragment, but I don't know whether that
   short-circuits the scoring operation. Would omitting the scoring
   improve performance?
2. I have considered refactoring my view to have a single widget for
   displaying a hit document as one blob of HTML or RTF text. That way,
   I could call the highlight method only one time instead of 10 or 15
   times (some ContentControls are inside an ItemsControl so there are
   multiple instances of some fields on the view). I expect this would
   significantly boost performance. The highlighting would be on text
   that was marked up with table formatting and such, but I suppose
   that would still work?
3. Is there something else I am missing that makes my highlight method
   so slow? Half a second seems way too slow - like I am really messing up something basic.

Comment: I have proceeded with option 2 and it works fine. I was afraid that the marked up HTML string would not be highlighted correctly due to the markup and because the Lucene documentation stresses that the content passed to the highlighter should match exactly the content originally indexed. But I suppose those docs were just a reminder to make sure your index is up-to-date. I'll keep the question open, since I feel this is a workaround instead of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an additional improvement as per the answer that I've already given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21683752/very-slow-highlight-performance-in-lucene/26438933?noredirect=1#comment47289859_26438933).

Comment: Thanks for your response!!  I will look into this further. I had actually seen this post before and had tried adding WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS, but didn't see much improvement. Now that I have gotten satisfactory performance (using option 2), I would like to do some speed testing and see the effect of this setting on various searches and highlighting operations. Since the text I am highlighting is an HTML aggregation of information from various fields in the source document, I am wondering if the positions and offsets will mean anything. I'll have to dig in and understand how that might work.

Comment: Ok, please notice that in order to see improvements you will need to re-index your content as you don't have any position and offset stored right now.